# How to augment an AWS IoT message in the same topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot, rules

In AWS IOT, I'm able to publish an MQTT message from a device to the topic "topic/messages" :

```
{
 "id":"messageID",
 "value":"messageValue"
}
```

And I want to "augment" it in the server by adding a timestamp on it and let the message to continue on the SAME TOPIC.

So I'd like that subscribers on "topic/messages" receive this:

```
{
 "id":"messageID",
 "value":"messageValue",
 "serverTimestamp":"1637867431920"     <--- Here
}
```

However, I don't find the way how to process this message and let it flow in the same topic:

I can add a rule

```
SELECT * , timestamp() as serverTimestamp FROM 'topic/#'
```

But the rule does not augment the original message but creates an augmented copy and redirects it to some other service (Lambda, DynamoDB, Republish, etc..)

Those services work with the copy of the given value, but not with the original message, so the subscribers still receives the original sent message.

```
{
 "id":"messageID",
 "value":"messageValue"
}
```

I can republish the message using the same topic BUT as the topic has an attached rule, after the republishing, the rule's action is triggered again and again in a recursive loop)...

All the AWS examples I've read are meant to take the message, transform it , and do some other different thing with it (save in DynamoDB, save in a Bucket, end to Salesforce....) but none of them modify the message to be sent.

So what I'm looking for is a way to receive the message, add  a field (or more) to it and let it flow in the same topic .

What is the simplest way to do this?